# Can someone be bound to a contract to which they are not a party?

Tags: settlement, litigation

I am reviewing a contract, to which I am a party, drawn up by the other party. There is a section that mandates the actions of an individual who is not a party to this contract; the contract does not require that individual's signature. If I sign this, is that individual bound to this contract?

Note that it does not mandate that I, a party, ensure that the unrelated individual behaves according to the contract.

Answer (score 3):

An important doctrine of contract law is [privity of contract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privity_of_contract), to the effect that only parties to an agreement have legal obligations and benefits from the contract. However, there can be [third-party beneficiaries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third-party_beneficiary), where a third person may gain a benefit, and may rely on that benefit. For example, A agrees to work for B, who will pay C (perhaps because A owes money to C); C can then sue B for non-payment. In order for this right to materialize, C's rights must have "vested", for example C must have relied on the agreement to his detriment, or he has agreed to this with at least one party, or there can be some clause in the contract whereby his rights vest.

That said, in order for a person to by *obligated* by a contract, they must be a party to the contract – they must have agreed to take on an obligation. (A person can also be obligated, without assent, if there is a specific law – e.g. you are obligated to pay the government your taxes, even if yo didn't agree to it).

Comment: Thank you for your response and for providing resources for further exploration.

Comment: Your obligation to pay taxes, while a legal obligation, is not a contractual one.

Comment: Yes, my statement was about (legal) obligations in general, not obligations under contract.

Comment: An aside: I believe there is no law that would bind the non-party individual to the obligations named in the contract.

Comment: Follow-up question: if a contract says that I, the party, must force a non-party to do something, is the contract valid? What if I cannot force a non-party to behave as the contract mandates?

Comment: @khrabanaz In the US (and I assume the entire civilized world), *forcing* someone to do something is generally a serious crime. A contract to commit a crime (e.g. the crime of coercion) is invalid. That said, it's very common for a contract to depend on the performance of a nonparty; a prime contractor on a house may not be an electrician, but they take on the responsibility of hiring one. If the electrician does something bad, the prime contractor is liable to the owner and the electrician is liable to the prime contractor.

Comment: @cpast What if the contract does not use the words "force" or "coerce"-- what if it says I, a party, have to have a non-party behave a certain way and I'm not sure if I can really do that. Am I liable for this non-party's behavior? If the homeowner says that the prime contractor must have a specific electrician, Electrician A, fix an outlet, but the prime contractor is unable to sway Electrician A to do this, what happens?

Comment: "privity of contract" is the doctrine in common law systems that only a party to a contract can benefit from it (unless in privity of estate). Many common law systems have introduced ways in which third parties may benefit. I should add that wikipedia is not a good source *at all* for this.

Comment: In answer to a question (which you should really add as a question), it is perfectly possible to have a contractual obligation to procure the performance by another of an obligation. In fact that is very common in all sorts of contracts. Eg an individual's contracting company contracts to procure that they perform certain tasks. If they do not perform, the company is liable.

Comment: Privity of contract seems to be specific to common law. Looking at the "Principles of European Contract Law", it appears that the more general principle is that the remedies in case of non-performance can only apply to a contract party.